# Display a inserted info from a php program to a database and then display the infor inserted

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to display the info entered by the user from a php program after data is submitted and has been inserted into a database.  When I run it, I can't see any results. I just get a blank page. I can't find the error in my code, I hope you guys can help me find it, so I can fix it and move on. THIS IS ONLY THE PART OF MY CODE THAT I WANT TO INSERT SOME INFO TO MY DB AND THEN DISPLAY IT WHAT I HAVE INSERTED...

```
if ( $valid ) { 
    $lines = file('/home/user/Documents/file.txt');
    $uid = trim($lines[0]);
    $pw = trim($lines[1]);
    $dbserver = trim($lines[2]);
    $dbname = trim($lines[3]);

    //Connecting to mysql
    $link = mysqli_connect($dbserver, $uid, $pw, $dbname);
    or die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());

    //Our SQL Query
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $organization = $_POST['organization'];
    $emailaddress = $_POST['emailaddress'];
    $phonenumber = $_POST['phonenumber'];
    $sql_query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$organization','$emailaddress','$phonenumber')";

        //Run our sql query
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql_query) or die('query failed'. mysql_error());

    // Get all records now in DB
    $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM table";
    //Run our sql query
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql_query) or die('query failed'. mysql_error());

    //iterate through result printing each record
    echo "<br>Names in DB: <br>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row['firstname'];
    echo $row['lastname'];
    echo $row['organization']; 
    echo $row['emailaddress'];
    echo $row['phonenumber'];
    echo "<br>";
    }

    // Free resultset (optional)
    mysqli_free_result($result);

    //Close the MySQL Link
    mysqli_close($link);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection, immediately stop using it. [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: Your missing a `('` ill leave it upto you to find where...

Comment: I heartily encourage you to read about cleaning your query values that come from the outside world. Your code as it stands now is very vulnerable to mischief.

Comment: You really should stop whatever you're doing right now and spend the small amount of time it takes to [read up on SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and how to use [PDO properly](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). This code is full of mistakes that you would recognize if you knew about these things.

Answer (score 0):

Change $sql_query = `"INSERT INTO table VALUES $firstname','$lastname','$organization','$emailaddress','$phonenumber')";`

to

```
$sql_query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ($firstname','$lastname','$organization','$emailaddress','$phonenumber')";
```

Also the code you are writing is highly insecure and can easily be attacked by SQL injection.

Take some time to learn [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) insead of Mysql_* functions. Below is a basic query using a parameterized query with mysqli:

$query = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT COLUMN_LIST FROM TABLE WHERE COLUMN = ?");
$query->bind_param('s',$UNSAFE_VARIABLE);
$query->execute();

Comment: Hey, sorry it was my mistake missing the (' I already have them in my code. I was using frist MySQLi but I had same problem.. so, I just wanted to first make it work and then tried with MySQLi

Comment: ok, can you do a var_dump($result) after you set $result and post the results?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [mysqli_insertid](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)  if you insist on using the obsolete mysql functions instead I am sure there is a similar function.